# Python check if file object is in write mode

Tags: python-2.7, file, file-io

Is there a quick "pythonic" way to check if a file is in write mode, whether the mode is `r+`, `w`, `w+`, etc. I need to run a function when `__exit__` is called, but only if the file is open in write mode and not just read-only mode. I am hoping some function exists to obtain this information but I can't seem to find anything.

Is there a way to do this without having to build a separate function to interpret the list of mode types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `os.access('your_file_path', os.W_OK)` to check write mode.

`file.mode` always returns `'r'`, while the file is actually in 'write' mode.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. Maybe you're referring to when just doing `open("...")` as the [default mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) (when not supplied as an argument) is read ("r").  

`os.access` only tests if the invoking user has permissions to do the second argument (which in your case asked if the invoking user had permissions to write -- not whether the file was open in that mode)

Answer (score 2):

Simply by using `file.mode` attribute

```
>>> f = open("test.csv", "r")
>>> f.mode
'r'
```